# Testing distributed system

Tags: python, multithreading, testing, distributed-transactions

I've written a multi-threaded python program which has send/recv functions being executed as anonymous threads. I've ensured the send/recv are atomic(mutual exclusion ensured with threading.RLock()). Now I want to test the program.

1) Is there any framework to test my program ?
2) I want to test it on Cloud (AWS) too, how would I go about that ?

Comment: You can use `pyunit` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), the standard Python unit test framework for writing and executing unit tests; the fact that your program is multithreaded is irrelevant. Can you be more specific on what exactly you need to run your tests?

Comment: I want to spawn processes on totally isolated nodes, each processes communicates with other processes over TCP. Each processes should send other process bunch of messages, each message will change the global variable values. On each event the processes write the output to a file or any persistent storage.